# get the filter value in nova metrics

Tags: laravel, laravel-nova

I'd like to create a Nova value metric that includes a filter that allows the user to select custom dropdown values instead of the standard date ranges.  In other words, the following array of date ranges is included in value metrics:

```
public function ranges()
{
    return [
        30 => __('30 Days'),
        60 => __('60 Days'),
        365 => __('365 Days'),
        'TODAY' => __('Today'),
        'MTD' => __('Month To Date'),
        'QTD' => __('Quarter To Date'),
        'YTD' => __('Year To Date'),
    ];
}
```

I want to be able to update this into custom key/value pairs, and reference this array in the calculate function:

```
public function calculate(NovaRequest $request)
{
    return $this->count($request, Model::class);
}
```

Is there a way to do this?  I couldn't find it in the Nova docs.

Comment: This could partially solve your problem: https://nova.laravel.com/docs/4.0/metrics/registering-metrics.html#refresh-after-filter-changes ^ You can refresh metrics after changing the filters for the records being displayed.

Answer (score 1):

An associative array is returned with the `ranges` method.  It typically returns  date ranges, but any values can be substituted.  These values can then be retrieved from the request like this:

```
    $filterValue = $request->query->get('range');
```